# Implement socket.io in electron app which communicates to a local webserver

Tags: node.js, windows, socket.io, electron

I have to make the locally running web server communicate with the locally running windows electron app in order to send some messages which the electron app would show it up as notifications .

I have seen people recommending socket.io for Real time communication between the client and the server but i am finding it hard to wrap my head around it as there are no examples which i can look into to see how it actually works .

Any sources and explanations for this topic are welcome .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go through [this tutorial](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/). Start from simple web. When you make it work - port it to electron.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks .

Comment: How to port it to electron?

Comment: javascript woo :)